# Randomly distribute a range values to a bigger range

Tags: vba, recursion

I'm building an automatic calendar project.
Input information is a task list for the month/year and an idea is to distribute exact values from the input list randomly over the output range.

I thought using a recursive vba function

```
Sub distributeRandomly()
    Dim InRng as Range
    Dim OutRng as Range
    Dim distributePercent as Single
    Set InRng=Application.InputBox("Select input range",Type:=8)
    Set OutRng=Application.Input("Select output range",Type:=8)
    distributePercent=InRng.count/OutRng.count
    distributeRandomlyRec(InRng,OutRng,distributePercent)
End Sub

Function distributeRandomlyRec(InRng As Range,OutRng as range,distributePercent as Single)
    Dim i1 As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    if OutRng.count=0 or InRng.count=0 Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        Randomize
        If distributePercent <= Rnd Then
            Randomize
            i1=int(OutRng.count*Rnd+1)
            Randomize
            i2=int(InRng.count*Rnd+1)
            OutRng.Cells(i1).value=InRng.Cells(i2).value
            ##Here i stacked to define a new ranges without the choosen cells i1 and i2
            ##Maybe convert old range to array , delete a value and then 
            ##Transpose() an array to a new range ?
            ##NewOutRng = ?
            ##NewInRng = ?
            if NewOutRng.count=0 or NewInRng.count=0 Then
                Exit Function 
            else 
                distributePercent=NewInRng.count/NewOutRng.count
                distributeRandomlyRec(NewInRng,NewOutRnge,distributePercent)
        End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the code - no recursive version , tested

```
Sub distributeRandomly()
    Dim InRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim inCollection As New Collection
    Dim outCollection As New Collection
    Dim i1 As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim distributePercent As Single

    Set InRng=Application.InputBox("Select input range",Type:=8)
    Set OutRng=Application.InputBox("Select output range",Type:=8)
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In InRng
        inCollection.Add c.Value
    Next
    
    While inCollection.Count > 0
        If (OutRng.Count - outCollection.Count) > 0 Then
            Randomize
            distributePercent = inCollection.Count / (OutRng.Count - outCollection.Count)
            If distributePercent >= Rnd Then
                Randomize
                i1 = Int(inCollection.Count * Rnd + 1)
                outCollection.Add inCollection(i1)
                inCollection.Remove (i1)
            Else
                outCollection.Add (vbNullString)
            End If
        End If
    Wend

    For i2 = 1 To outCollection.Count
        OutRng.Cells(1, i2).Value = outCollection(i2)
    Next

End Sub
```